# Dialogflow REST API to get user utterances for an intent

Tags: dialogflow-es

We have used Dialogflow AI engine to build Virtual Assitant. Currently we are working on a use case to auto suggest user with related questions soon as user starts typing a question in chat window.

We are planning to consume configured user utterances for a particular intent.Does Dialogflow support a REST API which can be used for this purpose.

Comment: this libraray might help when you get intent through this library you get all utterances of that intent as well, https://www.npmjs.com/package/dialogflow-helper I wrote this library on the top of dialogflow rest client

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can access the utterances ('trainingPhrases' in Dialogflow terminology) of a given intent via the [projects.agent.intents](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/v2beta1/projects.agent.intents) endpoint of the Dialogflow v2beta1 REST API. See also the [client SDKs](https://dialogflow.com/docs/sdks#v2beta1_client_libraries) if you want to do this programmatically.

Comment: this libraray might help, https://www.npmjs.com/package/dialogflow-helper I wrote this library on the top of dialogflow rest client